# Blob audio file is corrupted after being recorded in browser with getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, corruption

I record audio with my browser and then send a blob file to my server via ajax. I can open it with player and hear my voice. However it is corrupted, despite having a couple of seconds of recording, the player shows the audio is 435 hours long. I want to send it in binary to transcription service and it does not recognize the file in this form. What are my options? Can i somehow fix it with python or set the metadata correctly with js.

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
    var blob = new Blob(chunks, {'type': 'audio/wav'});

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('audio', blob, 'audio.wav');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/ajax/get_file/',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
              console.log(response)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell the recorder what format to use:

```
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'audio/wav'});
```

Then don't lie about the format in the blob constructor:

```
const blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: chunks[0].type});
```

Comment: That would only work if `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/wav')` is `true`. I have yet to see a browser where this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i used Recorder.js instead it has built in wav export. The metadata is set properly now